# Latency issues with self-hosting a simple NancyFX HelloWorld application running under Mono

Tags: c#, mono, servicestack, nancy, self-hosting

**Background**

I'm testing the NancyFX framework by running a simple HelloWorld example under different conditions.

```
public class IndexModule : NancyModule
{
  public IndexModule()
  {
    Get["/"] = _ => "Hello World!";
  }
}
```

Example seems to run fine on both Windows and Linux, the problem is Mono's response time. Under Windows the HTTP response takes aprox. 3-4ms, whereas the same code under Linux (Mono) always takes 200ms+. After some additional testing (and switching to ServiceStack AppHost) the problem persists, so my guess would be this has something to do with Mono. Any ideas?

**HTTP response (CentOS 6.5, Mono 3.10)**

[image: centos_mono_nancyfx_http_response]

**Test results**

```
OS                  Runtime          Response time    Location
Windows 7           .NET 4.5.1       3ms              Local
CentOS 6.5          Mono 3.10        200ms            Local
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS    Mono 2.10.8.1    295ms            Remote
```

**Other**

[Source code](https://gist.github.com/wickedsheep/8e701142bf03b928c909)

[Profile dump](http://pastebin.com/PSLqfiwY)

Comment: I don't think it will make any diff but see Thread.Sleep(infinite) here https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-Nancy-with-Nginx-on-Ubuntu#create-nancy-website

Comment: @Jon Makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough, if you put a reverse proxy on top of the self-hosted app, the latency issues disappear.

Here's the nginx proxy_pass config used:

```
# /etc/nginx/virtual.d/nancydemo.conf

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name nancydemo.local;
  root /media/sf_dev/nancydemo/bin/Debug;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nancy self host isn't really meant to be used by its self. Its really only for testing and low usage. For anything else it should have a web server handling connections like apache or nginx.